# Complex number assignment

Tags: c++, matlab, math, complex-numbers

Here is my MATLAB code which calculates the fresnel diffraction.And i wanna implement the same code in C++.

```
clc;clear all;close all;

N=512;
M=512;
lambda=632e-9;
X = 12.1e-6;
k=2*pi/lambda;
z0 = (N*X^2)/lambda;
a = (exp(j*k*z0)/(j*lambda))
hX=(exp(j*k*z0)/(j*lambda))*exp(j*pi/(z0*lambda)*X^2*[0:N-1].^2);
hY=(exp(j*k*z0)/(j*lambda))*exp(j*pi/(z0*lambda)*X^2*[0:M-1].^2);
h = hX.'*hY;
figure; imshow(real(h), []);
```

And while im trying to implement the same code in C++ I tried this:

```
int main (){
std::complex<double> com_two(0,1);
double mycomplex = 1;
double pi = 3.1415926535897;
double N = 512;
double M = 512;
double lambda = 632e-9;
double X = 12.1e-6;
double k = (2*pi)/lambda;
double z0=(N*pow(X,2))/lambda;
//std::complex<double> hx; // Both definitions don't work
//double hy;
/*for (int j=0; j < N; j++){
    hy = (exp(mycomplex*k*z0) / (mycomplex*lambda))*exp(mycomplex*pi/(z0*lambda)*pow(X,2)*pow(j,2));
    cout << hy <<endl;
}*/
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

But the thing is that while calculation performing hx and hy values return complex values.

So How should i define the "mycomplex" like i,j as in the MATLAB code. 
Also I found some asssignments like `std::complex<double> complex;`

But i guess that won't work.In my opinion i have to get hx and hy values as complex numbers.But I couldn't find a proper solution.

I'll be very glad if someone helps about that.

Comment: so what is the problem? hy is complex or not?

Comment: Yes it has to take complex numbers like 5+3i etc. Right side of the equation gives complex numbers but when i try to display result it gives 1#INF to me which i dont wanna get.

Comment: where is your declaration of hy? plese paste it

Comment: I tried both 'std::complex<double> hy;' 'double hy;' and they dont work

Comment: please insert real code! we can't say anything based on this snippet!

Comment: how do you declare hy, how do you print it? show your errors!

Comment: if hx is complex in your snippet, hy probably should be complex too. why hx is complex and hy is double?

Comment: It looks like `mycomplex` should be `std::complex<double> mycomplex(0,1);`. And hy should be declared as complex too.

Comment: I pasted my full code.If i use std::complex<double> hy version i get <1.#INF,0> for each iteration. In normal double definition version i get 1.#INF values for each iteration.

Comment: While defining hy how it should be? Like this  std::complex<double> hx; if you say like this, although i changed my code as you said i got fatal error!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not complex number itself, but calculations that you perform. First you do different things in Matlab alg (the version that you showed at least) and in C++. Here is how you should port this code to C++.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double pi = 3.1415926535897;
    double N = 512;
    double M = 512;
    double lambda = 632e-9;
    double X = 12.1e-6;
    double k = (2 * pi) / lambda;
    double z0 = (N * pow(X, 2)) / lambda;
    std::complex<double> hx, hy; // Both definitions don't work
    //double hy;
    int j = 1;
    //for (int j=0; j < N; j++){
        hy = (exp(j*k*z0) / (j*lambda))*exp(j*pi/(z0*lambda)*pow(X,2)*pow(j,2));
        cout << hy <<endl;
    //}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

now the problem is in your `lambda = 632e-9` which is close to zero, then k is very big `k = (2 * pi) / lambda;` as the inverse of something which approaches 0, and in turn

```
exp(j*k*z0)
```

is very big, and this

```
(exp(j*k*z0) / (j*lambda))
```

even more. Then this

```
(exp(j*k*z0) / (j*lambda))*exp(j*pi/(z0*lambda)
```

is huge, and the remaining factor `pow(X,2)*pow(j,2))` is meaningful. So then

```
cout << hy <<endl;
```

will print `(inf,0)` even for lambda = 0.0001; (how about 632e-9 !).

However you can still print it if you use small enough `j` value to absorb huge `k` value in exp (`j` is also in denominator but [de l'Hopital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) will assure this will be smaller).

As follows from your comments (not your code) you wanted `j` to be complex number z=1i. Then the solution is to change

```
double j =1;
```

to

```
std::complex<double> j(0,1);
```

---

SOLUTION:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double pi = 3.1415926535897;
    double N = 512;
    double M = 512;
    double lambda = 0.00001;//632e-9;
    double X = 12.1e-6;
    double k = (2 * pi) / lambda;
    double z0 = (N * pow(X, 2)) / lambda;
    std::complex<double> hx, hy;
    std::complex<double> j(0,1);
        hy = (exp(j*k*z0) / (j*lambda))*exp(j*pi/(z0*lambda)*pow(X,2)*pow(j,2));
        cout << hy <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `j` is imaginary 1 in matlab. Here - it is a real positive number. That is the main error.

Comment: I have used int j as this is what you have showed in your code, no problem to use complex(0,1) instead

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a few lines in your code and it gives results different from 1#INF

1) Change `mycomplex` from `double` to `std::complex<double>` and assign `(0,1)` to make it imaginary 1. Actually `com_two` has the same type and value you need for `mycomplex` and you are not using it.

2) Remove comments. Change `hy` type from `double` to `std::complex<double>`. Remove unused `hx` declaration.

3) My compiler finds an error at `pow(j,2)` because of ambiguity, so i fixed it too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main (){
  complex<double> mycomplex(0,1);
  double pi = 3.1415926535897;
  double N = 512;
  double M = 512;
  double lambda = 632e-9;
  double X = 12.1e-6;
  double k = (2*pi)/lambda;
  double z0=(N*pow(X,2))/lambda;
  complex<double> hy;
  for (int j=0; j < N; j++){
      hy = (exp(mycomplex*k*z0) / (mycomplex*lambda))*exp(mycomplex*pi/(z0*lambda)*pow(X,2)*pow((double)j,2));
      cout << hy <<endl;
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have changed the code. OP uses double mycomplex = 1; and it is totally different from your complex<double> mycomplex(0,1); which is imaginary "1i"

Comment: Yes I mentioned it in `1)`. That's actually what OP wants to make code similar to matlab, where `j` is imaginary 1.

Comment: this is not MATLAB that uses j but OP, he declared this as imaginary j, as we now know, but didn't mention it, however showed us int, omg